# Help to solve equation with trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

I was obviously not clear enough in my first question, so I will reformulate. I have the following equation
$$
A=\frac{B\sin 2\theta}{C+D\cos 2\theta}
$$
where $A,B,C,D$ are variables.
I need to solve or rewrite the equation to easily obtain $\theta$ (or $2\theta$), given known values for $A, B, C, D$. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: what means $$sen(2\theta)$$?

Comment: The trigonometric functions are denoted in latex as follows: \sin x, \cos x, \tan x. Also, there are too many variables. Did you really mean $\phi$ and $\theta$??

Comment: Thank you for editing, and sorry for that... what I need is to solve the equation for $\theta$ as the only variable, of course the rest of the variables ($x, y, \phi$) will have known values, which will allow me to obtain the value for $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use that $$\sin(2x)=\frac{2\tan(x)}{1+\tan(x)^2}$$ and $$\cos(2x)=\frac{1-\tan(x)^2}{1+\tan(x)^2}$$ and let $a=\tan(x)$

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but couldn't solve for $\theta$

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to this question thanks to friends in other forums, maybe it is useful to share it here.
I replaced $\sin 2\theta$ by $\sqrt {1-\cos²2\theta}$; replacing $\cos 2\theta=x$ then squared everything to get rid of the square root, afterward passed everything to the LHS and factorized, which gives a quadratic equation of the second degree, with variable $x$, equaled to zero. This is solved by the traditional manner (e.g. baskhara).